Get full file path when running file via a script on MAC OSX terminal
I'm running let's say a .txt file via my .sh script.
I would like to add a line to my script which stores the just-opened file's full path (+ filename with extension included) as a variable.
In windows batch i used to do "set path=%~dp1%~nx1"
Is there an alternative on macos?

Put these two variable assignments at the top of your script.
user_file="$1"If you run the script: ./script.sh my_file.txt the first argument is $1, (i.e. my_file.txt)
This will capture the file as the first positional parameter.
primary_working_directory="$PWD" $PWD gives you the current path.
(Also, $OLDPWD will give you the previous path.)
#!/bin/bash

user_file="$1"
primary_working_directory="$PWD"

echo 'The name of this script is always $0'
echo 'The single quotes will treat all characters as a string.'
echo "If you run the script: ./$0 my_file.txt"
echo "The first argument (i.e my_file.txt) is $user_file"

echo ".$primary_working_directory/$0 $user_file"
echo "is the same as:"
echo "./your/current/path/script.sh my_file.txt"

exit 0

